# require.config TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, jasmine

I want to write some tests with Jasmine. Therefore I first want to load RequireJS.
Thus I put a reference in the Jasmine.json file:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js",
    "../node_modules/requirejs/require.js",
    "../public/js/app/config/config.js"
  ]
}
```

The config file starts with this:

```
require.config({...
```

When I start Jasmine it gives this error:

> require.config({
>           ^
>
> TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object. (C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3\public\js\app\config\co
>   nfig.js:4:9)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>
> at require (module.js:384:17)
>
> at C:\Users\Garrarufa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:69:5
>
> at Array.forEach (native)
>
> at Jasmine.loadHelpers (C:\Users\Garrarufa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:68:
>   20)

config is undefined, but why?